# Is possible to do proxy authentication using SQL Server JDBC driver?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Oracle JDBC driver provides option to do proxy authentication for multi-tier architecture design. Are there any similar/equivalent option available with SQL Server JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're presuming SQL Server can do [multi-tier architecture](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c23acces.htm#6342).

If you're running SQL Server, there are three options for distributing databases:

1. Create separate servers that contain different tables.  In this scenario, the tables that have to be shared use linked database servers.  (The authentication for linked servers does not come from the client, but from the server's/link's configuration.)
2. Create separate servers that contain the same tables.  In this scenario, any updates on one server will have to be replicated to the other servers.  (This could also be done via triggers across the linked servers, but that slows things down.)
3. Don't.

If you are trying to link servers, JDBC drivers won't have anything to do with that.